# Datatable jquery MVC PHP no funciona

Tags: php, mvc

estoy trantando de llamar datatable jquery siguiendo el mvc con php pero me sale el siguiente error

DataTables warning: table id=dataClientes - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1

En el modelo tengo el siguiente código:

```dart
 public function getClientes() {   
            
            $sql="SELECT * FROM clientes";
            $consulta=$this->db->prepare($sql);
            $consulta->execute();
            $resultado=$consulta->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);    
            $resultado= json_encode($resultado,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);    
            return $resultado;          
        }
```

En el controlador:

```dart
 public function ver(){
        require_once("views/clientes/v_clientes.php");
        $response= $this->cliente->getClientes();  
        echo $response;
    }
```

En la vista:

```dart
  <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataClientes" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>id</th>
                          <th>nombre</th>
                          <th>telefono</th>
                          <th>email</th>
                          <th>dirección</th>
                          <th>Ciudad</th>
                          <th>Departamento</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                    </table>
```

En el JS

```dart
window.onload = () => {
  $("#dataClientes").DataTable({
    ajax: {
      url: "http://localhost/2020/MVC-NEW/clientes/ver",
      dataSrc: "",
      dataType: "json",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    },
    columns: [
      { data: "id" },
      { data: "nombre" },
      { data: "telefono" },
      { data: "email" },
      { data: "direccion" },
      { data: "ciudad" },
      { data: "departamento" }
    ]
  });
};
```

En inspeccionar elemento /red recibo el json

```dart
[
    {
        "id": "805264",
        "nombre": "Juan José",
        "telefono": "222222",
        "email": "abc@gmail.com",
        "direccion": "calle abc",
        "ciudad": "bogotá",
        "departamento": "cundinamarca"
    },
    {
        "id": "2525244",
        "nombre": "Carla Perez",
        "telefono": "222222",
        "email": "abc@gmail.com",
        "direccion": "calle abc",
        "ciudad": "bogotá",
        "departamento": "cundinamarca"
    },
    {
        "id": "90520555",
        "nombre": "Victor Reyes",
        "telefono": "2222222",
        "email": "abc@hotmail.com",
        "direccion": "calle abc",
        "ciudad": "Madribogotá",
        "departamento": "cundinamarca"
    }
]
```

La verdad no se porque me da ese error. He tratado de mil formas y me sale siempre el mismo error, al parecer es un error de formato json pero cuando valido la respuesta en https://jsonlint.com/ me dice que el json es válido.  Me preguntaba si alguien me puede colaborar con este issue. Gracias de antemano

Comment: No sé si será el problema, pero tienes mal planteado el comportamiento del Modelo y del Controlador. Tal y como lo tienes es el Modelo el que está enviando datos a la Vista, cuando debería ser el Controlador. Tu Modelo debería devolver el resultado de la consulta al Controlador y este hacer el `echo` del `json_encode()` de dicha respuesta.

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta y coloca el código como texto, porque en imagen resulta más difícil analizar. Ayúdanos a ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

ya edite la pregunta y cambie las imagenes por texto. También hice el echo en el controlador en lugar de hacerlo en el modelo y sigo obteniendo el mismo error. Gracias por la colaboración